# Set UserName as foreign key

Tags: entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created an mvc4 webapi project in VS2012RC and used EF4.3 in my project for Code first.
I used default membership provider. How can i use the UserName as foreign key in another model.

I tried this code ,

```
    [ForeignKey("RegisterModel")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual RegisterModel User { get; set; }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `UserName` because `UserName` is not primary key in `Users` table. Only primary keys from principal table can be used as foreign keys in dependent table when using EF because EF doesn't understand unique constraints used in database.